# Unable to import 'soap' module from aws lambda layer using es6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have few aws lambda functions (Node.js 18.x) that uses soap module with different version at the same lambda.For this scenario, I planned to store my modules on aws layers. below is the structure of the module layer.

`nodejs/soap/latest/node_modules`

`nodejs/soap/0.33.0/node_modules`

When I import the module with this code `import soap from '/opt/nodejs/soap/latest/node_modules/soap';`
I'm getting this error `Directory import '/opt/nodejs/soap/latest/node_modules/soap' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /var/task/index.mjs\nDid you mean to import /opt/nodejs/soap/latest/node_modules/soap/index.js?",`

Basically my plan is to store all modules in one layer with multiple versions.
I understand that `soap` does not use es6 yet but my requirement is to use es6.
I can import the soap module using `require()` for commonJs but what if there will be a latest version of soap that uses es6 and I updated my layer. basically, I will need to update all my lambda functions that uses this module.

Is there something wrong I'm doing with the import? or any better implementation I can use if this is really feasible?

I tried to use require() and it worked. But using es6 import I'm getting error.